# Sticky Navigation Menu not sticking to the top properly

Tags: html, css, scroll, navigation, carousel

my knowledge of web tech is mostly HTML and CSS.
I've used bootstrap and jQuery to allow the navigation to get stuck on scroll, it did for a while and then stopped once I started adding new pages. Here's my JavaScript:

```
$('.carousel').carousel({
    interval: 5000 //changes the speed
})

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    //if you hard code, then use console
    //.log to determine when you want the 
    //nav bar to stick.  
    console.log($(window).scrollTop())
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 280) {
      $('#nav_bar').addClass('navbar-fixed');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < 281) {
      $('#nav_bar').removeClass('navbar-fixed');
    }
  });
});
```

Here's [my web page](http://aasunm01.wdd1516.bbkweb.org/Assignment%201/LPhotography.html) where you can see the issue. What can I do about it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your javascript, you are looking to apply the class `nav-bar-fixed` to an element with the ID `nav_bar`. However, you don't have that ID put on any element.

```
 if ($(window).scrollTop() > 280) {
   $('#nav_bar').addClass('navbar-fixed');
 }
 if ($(window).scrollTop() < 281) {
   $('#nav_bar').removeClass('navbar-fixed');
 }
```

But, when I add and ID to `<nav>` it works. It needs some modification to look good, but it does work then. `<nav id="nav_bar">`

I'm guessing that with the new pages you created, you just missed adding the ID or copied an older version of code, etc.

Comment: @Dee no problem. Go ahead and mark as accepted so others that are troubleshooting similar problems can find the answer.

Comment: how do i do that, i'm new here, i've looked around but can't seem to see anything that says "answer accepted"

Comment: Looks like you already figured it out. The green checkmark to the left of my answer indicates that. Being that you're new, you can also upvote or downvote answers/questions that you find helpful.